# Kubectl apply failing to create EBS volume persistent volume claim

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-ebs, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to create an encrypted persistent volume claim with an EBS StorageClass with the below k8s yaml:

```
    ---
#########################################################
# Encrypted storage for Redis AWS EBS
#########################################################
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: encrypted-redis-data
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  encrypted: "true"

---
#########################################################
# Persistent volume for redis
#########################################################
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-data-encry
  labels:
    name: redis-data-encry
spec:
  storageClassName: encrypted-redis-data
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

Upon doing so the persistent volume claim is stuck in "Pending" status with the following error:

> Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "encrypted-redis-data": failed to create encrypted volume: the volume disappeared after creation, most likely due to inaccessible KMS encryption key

How can I fix this and create the EBS volume?

Comment: hi, not sure if this helps https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62171

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer thanks to IronMan. I added the proper KMS permissions to the EKS cluster and the volume was created. Answer found here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62171#issuecomment-380481349

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Minimal_EBS_KMS_Create_and_Attach",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext",
                "kms:CreateGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "key arn"
        }
    ]
}
```